# Find minimal polynomial for a period of 11th root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots-of-unity

> Let $\alpha=\zeta_{11}+\zeta_{11}^3+\zeta_{11}^4+\zeta_{11}^5+\zeta_{11}^9$. Find the minimal polynomial $m_{\alpha,\mathbb{Q}}(x)$, and likewise for $\gamma=\zeta_{11}+\zeta_{11}^{-1} $.

I started off by noting that since 11 is prime there is a $\beta$ such that: $\alpha+\beta=-1$, by the 11:th cylotomic polynomial. Here $\beta=\zeta_{11}^2+\zeta_{11}^6+\zeta_{11}^7+\zeta_{11}^8+\zeta_{11}^{10}$.

Also I have found $\alpha\beta=4+2(\alpha+\beta)$ and so $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial:

$$x^2+x+4+2(\alpha+\beta)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$

Is this correct? And if so how do we find the minimal polynomial for $\gamma$?

I believe this has something to do with

$$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})\cong(\mathbb{Z}|_{11}\mathbb{Z})^x\cong \mathbb{Z}|_{10}\mathbb{Z}$$

but I haven't made any advances as to how.

Comment: The minimal polynomial for $\gamma$ is easy to find. Just divide the equation $\sum_{i=0}^{10}x^{i}=0$ by $x^{5}$ and set $y=x+(1/x)$. Next note that $x^{j} +1/x^{j}$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $y$ of degree $j$. You then get desired polynomial in $y$. It is irreducible because original polynomial in $x$ is irreducible.

Comment: For general prime $p$ instead of $11$ you may study about Gaussian periods. See http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/12/gauss-and-regular-polygons-gaussian-periods.html and http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/12/gauss-and-regular-polygons-gaussian-periods-contd.html

Answer (score 1):

You result looks correct for $m_{\alpha,\mathbb{Q}}(x)$. Now you need to expand the powers of $\gamma$. I have chosen to align about the $\zeta^{-1}$ term so that addition in columns can be done with ease.
\begin{align*}
\gamma^5=\zeta^5+5\zeta^3+10\zeta+&10\zeta^{-1}+5\zeta^{-3}+\zeta^{-5}\\
-4\gamma^3=-4\zeta^3-12\zeta-&12\zeta^{-1}-4\zeta^{-3}\\
3\gamma=3\zeta+&3\zeta^{-1}
\end{align*}
and (aligned about the 6)
\begin{align*}
\gamma^4=\zeta^4+4\zeta^2+&6+4\zeta^{-2}+\zeta^{-4}\\
-3\gamma^2=-3\zeta^2-&6-3\zeta^{-2}
\end{align*}
It follows that 
\begin{equation}
\gamma^5+\gamma^4-4\gamma^3-3\gamma^2+3\gamma+1=0 \hspace{1em} (1)
\end{equation}
This gives you your minimal polynomial.

Edit:

We know that $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})\cong (\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z})^\times$, so the Galois group has order 10. In addition, we have that 
\begin{equation*}
X^2-\gamma X+1\in\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)[X]
\end{equation*}
has $\zeta$ as a root. This tells us that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)]\leq2$. The relationship for gamma in (1) tells us that $[\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}]\leq 5$. $\gamma$ must satisfy some algebraic relationship in a polynomial of degree less than or equal to 5. By order considerations,
\begin{equation*}
10=[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)][\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}]
\end{equation*}
the inequalities are equalities! In other words, since $[\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}]=5$, I knew to look for a quintic relationship.

Comment: After some deliberation I see what you did. But still your answer is missing a motivation for why you chose the 5th power to begin with.

Comment: I'll edit my response to reflect this question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the ordering consideration made it a lot clearer. But I'm having a hard time extrapolating from your answer. You present another - to me - "magic" polynomial, this time of degree 2. It's easier to check this time but I'm no closer to dealing with periods of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ in the general case.

Comment: Any root of unity will satisfy the relationship $\zeta^2-(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})\zeta+1=0$.

Comment: Yes but what if we are given: $$\alpha=\zeta+\zeta^7+\zeta^{11}$$  where $\zeta$ is an 19th root of unity?

Comment: That element should have six conjugates (including itself); It will satisfy a degree 6 relationship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58969/discussion-between-gobucksmath-and-strange-brew).

Comment: $$(e^{(2\pi*i)/(11)}+e^{-(2\pi*i)/(11)})^5-4(e^{(2\pi*i)/(11)}+e^{-(2\pi*i)/(11)})^3+3(e^{(2\pi*i)/(11)}+e^{-(2\pi*i)/(11)})+1=0$$ In wolfram alpha is False, there seems to be a mistake in your minimal polynomial.

Comment: You are right! I forgot to include the even powers of $\zeta$. Now I end up with $\zeta^5+\zeta^4+\zeta^3+\zeta^2+\zeta+1+\zeta^{-1}+\zeta^{-2}+\zeta^{-3}+\zeta^{-4}+\zeta^{-5}=0$.

Comment: I still dont understand how to, in general, find the degree of the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ for a period of a pth primitive root of unity.